# What is .NET's approach for running very "big" async tasks?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, architecture

I wonder how .NET programmers deal with "big" tasks.

For example, a website user uploads a video file and our service should add some visual to it.

In Python, I would use Celery (or maybe just crontab) or RabbitMQ with some microservice to run the task separately from the website's execution thread.

But what is .NET's approach?

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong with this question. It makes me sad that people are voting for closing it or just give "-1" and give no explanation why. Feels like the community used to be friendlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would indeed recommend to do that outside the webservers process. You could use a [Worker Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) for that. Worker Services are actually meant to do this kind of heavy lifting. In combination with a rugged scheduling system like [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) you could periodically scan for new video files and process them. I have used (in production) a combination of both to run quite a bunch of out-of-webserver-process jobs with great success.

Answer (score 1):

Micro services are a good solution for these scenarios if the following requirements are included Otherwise, the use of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers is recommended

**When to Use Microservices:**

1- When you want your monolithic application to accommodate scalability, agility, manageability and delivery speed.

2- When you have to rewrite legacy applications in today’s programming languages or tech stacks to keep up with modern-day business requirements and solutions.

3- When you have standalone business applications or modules that have to be reused.
across diverse channels—some good examples would be login services, search options authentication facilities and more.

4- If you’re building a highly agile application (product or service) that demands swift speed of delivery, innovation and more.